# How to interprete RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass value?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, sentiment-analysis

I use CoreNLP version 3.3.0 for testing sentiment analysis. The code looks like this:-

```
val pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP("build.properties") // build.properties contain one line - "annotators = tokenize, ssplit, parse, sentiment"
...
pipeline.map { p =>
val annotation =  p.process(sentence)
annotation.get(classOf[SentencesAnnotation]).foreach { sen =>
    val tree = sen.get(classOf[AnnotatedTree])
    val sentiment = RNNCoreAnnotations.getPredictedClass(tree)        
    ...
}
```

I find that when passing sentence

- "Cats are stupid.", the value is 2;
- "Cats are amazing!" 0;
- "Wind is strong." 2.

I am confused because it is different from other program such as 'sentiment' module for node js where it would returns -2 for "Cats aare stupid.", and 4 for "Cats are amazing!".

```
{ score: -2,
  comparative: -0.6666666666666666,
  tokens: [ 'cats', 'are', 'stupid' ],
  words: [ 'stupid' ],
  positive: [],
  negative: [ 'stupid' ] }
{ score: 4,
  comparative: 1,
  tokens: [ 'cats', 'are', 'totally', 'amazing' ],
  words: [ 'amazing' ],
  positive: [ 'amazing' ],
  negative: [] }
```

And checking the java doc it only explain

> Return as an int the predicted class. If it is not defined for a node, it will return -1

http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/neural/rnn/RNNCoreAnnotations.html#getPredictedClass-edu.stanford.nlp.trees.Tree-

I am wondering how to interpret such value. Or am I calling the wrong function for obtaining sentiment score?

Thanks

The reason not using 3.4.0 or 3.5.2 comes from CoreNLP throws following exception

> edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.nlp.rnn.SimpleTensor

And it seems that the new version requires SimpleTensor in `edu.stanford.nlp.neural` package instead of `rnn`.

Answer (score 2):

See this answer on a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32447855

In summary:

```
0: "Very Negative"
1: "Negative" 
2: "Neutral" 
3: "Positive" 
4: "Very Positive"
```